# ionic3 cordova-plugin-facebook4 facebook install issues errors

Tags: facebook, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I seem to be having an issue with native plugins.

logPath: /Users/philipwilson/workspace/ionic/test2/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log

```
        [21:12:05]  console.log: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production 
                    mode. 
        [21:12:05]  console.log: Ionic Native: deviceready event fired after 542 ms 
        [21:12:05]  console.warn: Native: tried calling Facebook.browserInit, but the Facebook plugin is not installed. 
        [21:12:05]  console.warn: Install the Facebook plugin: 'ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4'
```

I have tried a lot of things.

```
 518  ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="99999999999" --variable APP_NAME="test2.com"
 565  ionic cordova build ios
 578  npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook
 593  ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4
 594  ionic cordova emulate ios -lc
```

I followed a few examples but still seeing issues with ionic 3 and angular4

Here is my info:
~/workspace/ionic/test2$ ionic info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.5.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.2
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.2
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.0.0
OS         : OS X El Capitan
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
ios-deploy : 1.8.3 
ios-sim    : 3.1.1 
npm        : 5.0.0
```

[image: install plugin]

[image: Run with ios lc]

[image: error when testing with run ios]
I have looked at these examples too:
 https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/
 https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-facebook-login

Anyone have any help?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: I've run into issues where I had to remove and then re-add my target platform in order to get a plugin to be installed correctly.

Comment: thanks.. I will give that a try

Comment: no luck.. I tried  cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-facebook4 - then reinstall with cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4@1.7.4 --save --variable APP_ID="<myid>" --variable APP_NAME="<myname>"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did, make sure you expose Facebook module on your `app.module.ts` file.

`app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule, ErrorHandler } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { AboutPage } from '../pages/about/about';
import { ContactPage } from '../pages/contact/contact';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    AboutPage,
    ContactPage,
    HomePage,
    TabsPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Facebook,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And in your `home.ts`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private fb: Facebook) {
    this.fb = fb

    console.log(fb)

    this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
      .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => 
        console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res)
      )
      .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));


    this.fb.logEvent(this.fb.EVENTS.EVENT_NAME_ADDED_TO_CART);
  }

}
```

If you forget include `Facebook` provider on `app.module.ts` file you will get your error: `"No provider for Facebook!"`

As a side note, make sure you use Simulator or Device to test login actions, otherwise it won't work.

Resources:
- https://javebratt.com/ionic-2-facebook-login/
- https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/facebook/

Comment: Hi, Thanks a ton. I worked on that issue for the last 3 days. I am new to Typescript and making a few errors. Thanks again !! Phil

Comment: Great to know this works. However, this seems like a very irregular thing to have do. Since `@ionic-native/facebook` is a third party angular package, it is weird that it is exposed like this considering that one does not and should not _provide_ services such as `FormBuilder` or `Http`, unless one needs to _replace_ them. I guess it is just more confusion stemming from Angular 2 introducing unnecessary proprietary patterns that overlap with common idioms in the language itself.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
But I was testing my mobile app on Ionic's DevApp application.
And later I find out, that not all native components are supported by Ionic's DevApp.

Following shows the list of supported plugins by Ionic's DevApp:
[List of supported plugins](https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/view.html#plugin-support)

After all I tested my facebook plugin straight on the ios-device it worked.
Even on the xcode-emulator.

Regards,
Oliver